# Slowness in mongo vanishes with restart

Tags: mongodb

Our production mongos suddenly start performing slow and if we restart the mongo db the problem vanishes. The performance degrades from ms to seconds and never recovers till we restart (or may be we havent waited long enough). I dont see anything in mongo logs. So thought this might be due to page faults

```
db.stats(1024*1024)

    "db" : "xrr",
    "collections" : 7,
    "objects" : 605843,
    "avgObjSize" : 3614.9300528354706,
    "dataSize" : 2088,
    "storageSize" : 2517,
    "numExtents" : 57,
    "indexes" : 41,
    "indexSize" : 383,
    "fileSize" : 8125,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
    },
```

Server status and working set seems to output

```
    "workingSet" : {
            "note" : "thisIsAnEstimate",
            "pagesInMemory" : 113607,
            "computationTimeMicros" : 23265,
            "overSeconds" : 830
    },
```

The mongo machines have 4 GB of ram and the working set size seems to be pretty low. So I dont understand why should there be pagefaults in this scenario as we have enough ram to accommodate half the database and all the indexes in memory. mms does show a slight increase pagefaults what I dont understand is why isnt the working set expanding to fit the records in memory and how is the issue fixing itself when i restart the mongos. We are using 2.4.1 version

I noticed the non mapped virtual memory is high ~2.4GB , I have only 100 -200 connections

```
rs_default:PRIMARY> db.serverStatus().mem
{
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 2275,
    "virtual" : 138017,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 67584,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 135168
}

rs_default:PRIMARY> db.stats(1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "xrr",
    "collections" : 7,
    "objects" : 605844,
    "avgObjSize" : 3614.9263836895307,
    "dataSize" : 2088,
    "storageSize" : 2517,
    "numExtents" : 57,
    "indexes" : 41,
    "indexSize" : 383,
    "fileSize" : 8125,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Is that too much ? we neede those indexes for our queries

Comment: More indexes probably slow down all of your write operations. Since MongoDB make database level lock for write operation, this also leads to slow process of read operation.

Comment: I see we have only 383 MB as index size which should easily fit our ram. Also we have very less number of writes when compared to reads. Mongo stat does not show any lock issues.